# In my shell script I would like to list all the files in my current directory

Tags: linux, shell

In my shell script I would like to list all the files and directories in my current directory.

I know the command is ls, but I have no idea how to run it in a shellscript.

Thanks for anyhelp.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far and details about how the actual results differ from the expected results.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) forums. People here will quickly bite your head off for asking such simple things. ;)

Comment: A shell script is just a list of commands. Just like at the prompt, you simply type the name of the command you want to run.

Comment: To "list" the contents of a directory you use `ls` (generally `ls -al` or `ls -l` or `ls -1`). Just start your shell script with `#!/bin/sh` for POSIX shell compatibility, or `#!/bin/bash` for bash, then type each line of the script just like you would enter it on the command line. If you want to list all the files recursively, consider `find ./` (or `find ./ -type f` for files only or `find ./ -type d` for only directories)

Comment: @AntonCavenaugh : Do you want to list all the **files** only, or **all entries** (i.e. including name of the subdirectories). In the latter case, you write for instance `ls -1a`; the `-a` ensures that hidden entries are displayed as well. In the first case, perhaps the `find` command is a better starting point, because you can restrict the processing to plain files.

Comment: Ok from the remarks, ls is the correct command.  And in my shellscript I had echo "list of files" $ls, which returned nothing. So I am guessing that the env where the shell script has been loaded to is an empty directory

Answer (score 1):

So you're basically asking:  what is a shell-script, how do I create one, and how do I run it ....

Use your editor of choice to create a file, give it the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh     # change to your preferred shell, sh being a low common denominator
command       # in your immediate question that would be `ls`
```

Save the file.

Run `chmod u+x file`  (not the word file, but what you called your saved script).

Then you can execute your file like so:

```
./file
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have created a shellscript that runs. But what I want to do is list all the files and directories in the directory the shellcript is running in and echo them out. I tried $ls is that the correct command within the shell script

Comment: No, `$ls` would be an (most likely) undefined variable. Just `ls`. @AntonCavanaugh

Comment: Ok thank you , now I know that $ls will not list what is in the current directory in a shellscript but it should be ls. Will give that a try.